# Código PHP y MySQL para mostrar el Número o ID cada vez que se vaya haciendo registro

Tags: php, mysql

help!! :) 
Lo que quiero saber es: cuando se realice un nuevo registro en unformulario, en ese mismo formulario se muestre un número de de registro ejemplo; 02. Es decir, si es el segundo registro, al yo ingresar a la pagina donde esta el formulario, me muestre de una vez en que numero de registro va, o sea,  cada vez que vaya a realizar un registro ya se esté mostrando el número de de registro dentro del formulario (que esto me lo muestre antes de enviar los datos) Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: que haz intentado? en que haz tenido errores? trata de leer [ask] y de paso checa el [tour] para que mejores tu pregunta, de otro modo pareciera que pides te hagan el trabajo saludos

Comment: por otro lado el id al ser un registro único y como veo que usas mysql, es de tipo auto incremental por lo cual se va a generar hasta que completes el registro y no antes de eso

Comment: Es cierto, Pues, el registro normal, lo llevo del formulario html a php con funcion mysql para insertarlo en la BD, alli no tengo problema. Por otra parte, tienes razon, el ID se va generando a partir del registro, en este caso tendria que realizar una consulta y mostrar el ultimo ID registrado.Entonces, de ser asi, que me recomiendas, que coloque un SELECT al lado del formulario para que me muestre y ya tenga una idea el numero de registro en el que voy.

Comment: Es decir, que en la misma página donde tengo  el formulario, me muestre el ultimo ID registrado.

Answer (score 1):

dependiendo de que libreria usaste para insertar el registro, te deberia retornar el ultimo id insertado, si es una tabla con ID que se autoincrementa. Aqui un ejemplo usando PDO.

```
function insert_user($firstname, $lastname){
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'username', 'password');
    $query = "  INSERT INTO users
        (firstname, lastname)
        VALUES (:firstname, :lastname)";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $firstname);
    $stmt->bindParam(':lastname', $lastname); 
    $stmt->execute();
    $id = $pdo->lastInsertId();
    return $id;}
```

Ahora si tu ID  no es "autoincremental" Asumo que tu pasas el ID, o si el ID es el resultado de pasar la data atravez de una funcion, pues que ese sea el returno de la funcion.

Para que puedas mostrar el ID que tu funcion en php retorna, tu Aplicacion Web, tienes que hacer el "submit" del formulario usado AJAX.

Aqui un ejemplo usando jquery

```
// AJAX
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "SubmitData.php",
    data: string,
    cache: false,
    success: function(result){
      alert(result.id); // en vez de alert, puedes asignar el valor a algun elemento en tu pagina
    }
});
```

Comment: aunque válida tu respuesta, la idea de SO no es solo darle la respuesta a quien pregunta si no ayudarle a corregir sus propios intentos, por otro lado le lanzas un ejemplo con PDO cuando no sabes si lo esta usando

Comment: Suprimí algunos campos para darte un ejemplo de lo que llevo... Lo primero es el formulario, que lo tengo en registro_1.php, que es el siguiente codigo.

Comment: <form action="registro_2.php>
      <input type="text" name="codigo_salida" required autofocus placeholder="Ingrese Código de Salida">
      <b>Seleccione Producto: <select name="producto_salida" required>
<?php
          require "../conexion.php";
         $registros=mysql_query("SELECT codigo_entrada,producto_entrada FROM inventario",$con) or die("Problemas en el select:".mysql_error());
while ($reg=mysql_fetch_array($registros))
   {echo "<option value=\"$reg[producto_entrada]\">$reg[producto_entrada]</option>";}
       ?>
        <input type="submit" >

Comment: <?php
require "../conexion.php";
$codigo_salida = $_POST['codigo_salida'];
$producto_salida = $_POST['producto_salida'];
$consulta="select *  FROM salida WHERE codigo_salida='$codigo_salida'";
$resultado=mysql_query($consulta,$con);
if(mysql_num_rows($resultado)>0)
{echo '<script>alert("Verifique: ¡Código de Salida ya se encuentra en uso!")</script>';
echo '<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;URL=principal.php">'; }else{
mysql_query("INSERT INTO salida VALUES ('','$codigo_salida','$producto_salida', '$fecha_salida')"); }
?>

Comment: Este código me funciona bien, sin ningún problema... Ahora, la duda que tengo como hago para colocar o mostrar en el primer archivo, o sea, el registra_1.php que es donde tengo el formulario, que me muestre el id registrado anteriormente, para mostrar y dar una idea de los N de registro que se han hecho hasta ahora.

Comment: ok si registra_1.php te vas a registra_2, puedes retorna a registra_1.php pasando el id como parametro .  `header("Location: http://example.com/registra_1.php?ID=" . $ID); exit();` y en registra_1.php agrega el echo. <?php if isset($_GET['ID']) echo $_GET['ID'] ?> Ahora, no te olvide the limpiar el valor antes de utilizarlo. Puedes hacer una conversion directa  ` (int)$_GET['id'];`  y luego verificar si lo es. NO LO USES DIRECTO EN OTRO QUERY A DB sin limpiarlo. Suerte